# Which are free disk space requirements for Date Tiered Compaction Strategy?

Tags: cassandra, cassandra-3.0

Size Tiered Compaction requires at least as much free disk space for compaction as the size of the largest column family. 
Leveled Compaction needs much less space for compaction, only 10 * sstable_size_in_mb.

Is DTCS free disk requirement like STC or worse ? 
Does it depend on max_sstable_age_days parameter ?

Answer (score 1):

Yes you are right,it will depend on max_sstable_age_days . In theory it should be 4 times the size of  biggest sstable which was created after the max_sstable_age_days parameter.

Example:

Suppose today is Oct 15,2016 and your max_sstable_age_days value is 365. Biggest sstable which was created after Oct 15,2015 is of size 1GB. You will require 4GB of free space to do the compaction.

The magic number 4 is coming from parameter named **min_threshold (default: 4)** you can also configure this while creating the table.